# Convert foreach loop to lambda expression

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

I'm new to lambda expressions but I think they look great in code, but I'm having problems understanding how to convert a foreach loop into a lambda. I can't understand the other examples I've seen here.

The code I'm trying to convert is:

```
{
    var a = arr.ToList();
    var b = a.Distinct().ToList();
    if(a.SequenceEqual(b)){return -1;}
    foreach(int i in b)
    {
        a.Remove(i);
    }    
    return a.First();
}
```

Specifically the

```
foreach(int i in b)
        {
            a.Remove(i);
        }
```

Also as I'm here, is `if(a.SequenceEqual(b)){return -1;}` an okay thing to do? I felt bad using like 4 lines when it could be only 1.

Comment: I think you meant Linq, not lambda.

Comment: @DavidG but when it has the "=>" it means it is a lambda expression, isn't it?

Comment: `(a.SequenceEqual(b))` Check the `Count` of each of them - much quicker.

Comment: I suspect you it will be markedly simpler to `GroupBy` then check the count > 2 then return the first match. One line of code, max.

Comment: Technically `GroupBy` will not return precisely the same result as the posted code. `GroupBy` will return groups in the same order as the first item that produces the key, but because of how `Remove` works, the posted code will remove the first occurrence of each item, and so which of the items with duplicates is "First" will be based on the position of the second such item. (In the example in my answer below the `GroupBy` solution would return `4` instead of `7`).

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/MOFqsE may be a reasonable _starting_ point.

Comment: @mjwills thank u for the example. I unfortunatelly suck balls at lambda/linq and didn't understand a single operator on it. Do u possibly have a link of where u learned at least the basics of it?

Comment: Break it down. Google each of them. In summary - `Reverse` reverses the order. `Select` is doing a projection to make all of the integers nullable. `GroupBy` buckets the numbers togethers` and then `Where` and `Count` finds the duplicates. `FirstOrDefault` finds the first group of duplicates (or `null` if there isn't one). `First` returns one of those first duplicates. `?? -1` returns -1 if there were no duplicates. But seriously, check MSDN for each of the operators one by one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the goal is to find the first item in the collection that has a duplicate, or to return `-1` when there are no duplicates, then it can be done with two lines

```
int FindFirstDuplicate(IEnumerable<int> arr)
{
  HashSet<int> seen = new();    
  return arr.SkipWhile(e => seen.Add(e)).DefaultIfEmpty(-1).First();
}
```

But these two lines cannot be written as expression-bodied function.

If there is a goal to write expression-bodied function then the easiest the way is to use `GroupBy`

```
int FindFirstDuplicate(IEnumerable<int> arr) => 
   arr.GroupBy(e => e)
      .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
      .Select(g => g.First())
      .DefaultIfEmpty(-1)
      .First();
```

But this option has a very suboptimal memory consumption.

If collection always has a very small number of elements then function can be written without `GroupBy`

```
int FindFirstDuplicate(IEnumerable<int> arr) => 
   arr.SkipWhile((e, i) => arr.Skip(i + 1).All(x => x != e))
      .DefaultIfEmpty(-1)
      .First();
```

But such implementation has quadratic complexity, as it has nested loop. So, it will be extremely slow for thousands records.

There is one more option that has similar performance and memory consumption as the very first function.

```
int FindFirstDuplicate(IEnumerable<int> arr) => 
   Enumerable.Repeat(new HashSet<int>(), arr.Count())
      .Zip(arr)
      .SkipWhile(e => e.First.Add(e.Second))
      .Select(e => e.Second)
      .DefaultIfEmpty(-1)
      .First();
```

`Repeat` and `Zip` are needed to pass the `HashSet` object to `SkipWhile` method.

And the most straightforward way with `foreach` loop for comparison with other options

```
int FindFirstDuplicate(IEnumerable<int> arr)
{
   HashSet<int> seen = new();
        
   foreach (int item in arr)
   {
      if (!seen.Add(item))
      {
         return item;
      }
   }

   return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to restate what your code does in English: you what to remove 1 of each unique value from a list, leaving duplicate values in place with the order unchanged.

For example if your input list was: `[ 4, 7, 1, 3, 7, 4, 8, 7 ]` you expect the [contents of `a`] to be `[ 7, 4, 7 ]`, and therefore the result would be `7` (<-- edited thanks to mjwills).

This is probably bad form because it uses a mutable accumulator, but it would work:

```
arr.Aggregate(
  new { Seen = new HashSet<Int32>(), Result = new List<Int32>() },
  (acc, val) => {
    if (!acc.Seen.Add(val)) {
      // If we've seen this value before, add it to the list
      acc.Result.Add(val);
    }
    return acc;
  }).Result
```

Obviously this does not remove elements from the original array, which is because it is not valid to remove elements from an array while you are using an enumerator with it.

Comment: Sorry I just meant the contents of `a`, the output of `First()` would obviously be `7` in my example

Comment: Given that OP only wants the first duplicate in the list, there is probably a more optimal solution, however `Aggregate()` does not support short circuiting (that is, returning a final value before all of the input is consumed).

Comment: First, wdym by "mutable accumulator" and why is it bad? Also, I always try to make my code as simple as possible (as I've always seen ppl recomend). Is my code bad? Lastly, could u help me specifically with the foreach loop?

Comment: Calls this overload of `Aggregate()` take a lambda that takes an accumulator and a value from the list. For each value in the list the lambda returns a new accumulator value which gets passed to the next call to the lambda for the next value. Best practice would be to have an immutable value for the accumulator and return a new accumulator. However, because of the way C# implements Aggregate on IEnumerable, there is nothing technically incorrect about the approach of modifying the accumulator (by adding elements to hashsets and lists) and simply returning the existing reference.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the original order of the items then this is super simple:

```
List<string> result = arr.GroupBy(x => x).SelectMany(xs => xs.Skip(1)).ToList();
```

Done. That removes one of each instance from the list.

If the original order is important then this is what you need:

```
List<string> result =
    arr
        .Select((x, n) => new { x, n })
        .GroupBy(y => y.x)
        .SelectMany(ys => ys.Skip(1))
        .OrderBy(y => y.n)
        .Select(y => y.x)
        .ToList();
```

If I run that on `var arr = new string[] { "x", "y", "z", "z", "x", };`  then I get `"z", "x"` as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think `Except` operator is more suitable here:

```cs
return a.Except(b).FirstOrDefault(-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this-
a.GroupBy(v => v).Where(c => c.Count() > 1).FirstOrDefault().Key;